# simplest multiplication is not working

Tags: php

try to convert INR TO USD and my code is

```
$url  = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=USD"; 
$usd = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "1 INR = ".$usd[0] .' USD <br/>';
$uusd=$usd[0];
echo $uusd * 105;
```

its give me `0` result, i don't know why ?

Comment: what is the value of $usd[0] ... I'm assuming it's 0 or something that when cast to a number becomes 0

Comment: the valu of `$usd[0]` is 0.017, have you run my script ?

Comment: cannot reproduce with supplied arguments. I get 1.785

Comment: I get 0.017. Guess it returns random, when no value is supplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert $usd[0] to float:

```
$url  = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=USD";
$usd = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "1 INR = ".$usd[0] .' USD <br/>';
$uusd = floatval($usd[0]);
echo $uusd * 105;
```

Comment: Exactly. simplexml_load_file returns a simplexmlelement which must be cast before it can be used properly.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed amount to web service. So, it assumes amount as 0. 0 INR = 0 USD.

Also, you operate on integer values. Even if for some reason web service returns 0.017 to you, when converted to integer, it's still 0. Use float.

Comment: but i get value in `$usd[0]`m its 0.017

Answer (score 0):

use float as your value is decimals

```
$uusd=(float)$usd[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url  = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=USD"; 
$usd = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "1 INR = ".$usd[0] .' USD <br/>';
$uusd = (float) $usd[0];
echo $uusd * 105;
```

You need to typecast `float`

```
$uusd = (float) $usd[0];
```